# Can I use MODEL-FIRST in EF5 withOUT losing the data in DB?

Tags: entity-framework-5

I am wondering about the model-first approach. I wish to design a new database using the model designer in VS2012.  The new features of the model designer such as coloring and splitting up model sections are wonderful.  Hopefully there will be purpose for using the model designer beyond initially creating a new database.

I would like to perform the following steps...

1. using the model designer, visually design and push the model to create the initial database and a table
2. add data to the table
3. make a change to the table in the model designer (e.g. add a field)
4. push the changes to the database (i.e. update the database)
5. NOT LOSE MY DATA FROM STEP 2.  Also, just to clear any confusion... did I mention that I DON'T WISH TO LOSE THE DATA?

Please, please tell me this obvious need (i.e. the need to evolve the the tables and their fields without losing data, starting from scratch) has not been overlooked in iteration FIVE of EF.

This page on EF (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx) makes things sound that the developer has equal choices between coding first and modeling first.  To me, the intro video on the page creates a similar impression.

It would be nice if there were a simple menu option or better yet just a way to establish "automatic pushes to DB" upon changes to the model.  That way whenever changes are made and the SAVE button is clicked, a dialog could appear "Update database?".

I see that using code-first there is a migrations option.  I cannot seem to find the same for model-first.  And I don't understand why this wouldn't be possible... after all the code that I would have written in code-first does indeed exist - it was created by the model-first code generation.

I'm keeping my fingers crossed in hopes someone will have a simple solution, perhaps something I've just overlooked and all this rambling/venting is in vain.  :-)

Comment: You may want to listen to the the dotNetRocks podcast with Julie Lerman: http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=816 Towards the end they talk about updating the database.

Comment: You may also want to read about "Automatic Code First Migrations" on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583

Answer (score 0):

You really have to use code-first if you want to modify your database when the model changes. Even then it's not some magical automated process but you'll have to script the changes.

With model first your best option is to generate a new database each time and create a change script (DDL) by using a tool like Redgate's SQL Compare or a [Visual Studio Sql Server Database Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty.aspx).

I'd like to add that it is virtually impossible to synchronize a database automatically with a model. Some changes require manual intervention, e.g. removing a field and adding another field cannot be distinguished from renaming/retyping a field. Some changed can easily be done in a model, but would require a table rebuild script in Sql Server (e.g. changing field order), or a combination of modified content and structure (e.g. making a field not null, adding a foreign key).

Comment: While disappointing to learn, I do appreciate your response and input.  I'm not sure how Telerik did it, but I have used their OpenAccess ORM and with the visual aid, am able to accomplish these tasks easily.  I guess I could use their ORM or look into your suggestions.  I was hoping to stick with EF since it's Microsoft's built-in tool.  Not sure how to separate paragraphs here...  one other note if I rename/add/remove/shorten/lengthen fields, I would expect a best effort from the EF model's GUI.

Comment: Maybe, but well, it just does not happen from the GUI. Some tools are probably smarter than Migrations. I can do more db refactorings in Toad than in SSMS, for example. But migrations is probably evolving with each release. Not much comfort for now, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the only thing to do is:

1. Copy your database file... (backup)
2. Allow EF to recreate the database according to model
3. Per table copy-paste your records from backup to your new db.

This is not that easy as you need to copy paste in a specific order because of relations and it will only be good for minor changes such as adding columns and new tables or removing scalar columns or removing tables.

But I am certain that this is the begining of a correct approach to deal with the problem which later on can be automated by writing a more generic migration app between two databases which share same table names and relations.

Deeper problems begin when the relations are not the same / table names changed / column names changed.